How to render images from react js public directory in node js app?
I have images in the client/public/images directory. I'm using a react js frontend with node js backend. My react js frontend is in client while the node js backend is outside the client directory in the root directory. How do I reference images in the client/public/images directory in my mustache file on node js backend?
I tried doing this in index.js in my root node js folder
app.use("/api/events", eventsApi);
app.use("/api/orders", ordersApi);
app.use("/", indexController.index);
app.use("/api/instructors", instructorsApi);
app.use("/api/admin/events", adminEventsApi);
app.use("/api/admin/orders", adminOrdersApi);
app.use("/api/admin/instructors", adminInstructorsApi);

app.use(express.static("client/public", { maxAge: tenMinutes }));
app.use(express.static("client/build", { maxAge: tenMinutes }));
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});


I assume your client in main directory of Node.js backend, Let me show you my example code:
// Serve public files
app.use("/client/public/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname,'client/public/images')));

or
// Serve sensitive files with authorization middleware
app.use("/client/public/images", <authMiddleware>, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public/images')));

You can change the /client/public/images path as per your requirement. Additionally, you can use it directly in your mustache file with https://<domain>/client/public/images.
